# NPM Start not starting local server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to make an react app using webpack and when I try to run npm start it should load `http://localhost:3333` but it says site cannot be reached, here is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: '/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3333
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And here is my script object from `package.json`: `"start": "webpack-dev-server"`. I have already installed webpack & webpack-dev-server globally. Check below image which I am getting:
[image]

Edit: My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sample",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/dheeraja00/react-app.git"
  },
  "author": "Dheeraj Agrawal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/dheeraja00/react-app/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.comdheeraja00/react-app#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "material-design-lite": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the output in the console when you run that command.

Comment: That's the problem its not showing anything in console, when I run npm start it gives all valid output in command line saying `(webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3333 3.97 kB {0} [built]` but when I load that in browser nothing happens

Comment: `nothing happens`. Do you mean a blank page, 404 or 'This site can't be reached'? Check your route if you use react-router. Check if the js file is loaded. Check your chrome dev tools for sources and console.

Comment: How about http://127.0.0.1:3333 Or http://0.0.0.0:3333 ?

Comment: @KhangLu check the screenshot I have added

Comment: Are you running `npm start` or `node start`?

Comment: @ppovoski `npm start`

Answer (score 4):

`npm start` will only work when you have a start script.

For the below example `webpack-dev-server` and `webpack` packages are required. To add these packages you should install `webpack-dev-server` and `webpack` globally.

```
npm install webpack-dev-server webpack -g
```

For Example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
 }
```

in you **package.json**, basically when you run npm start it searches your **package.json** for what to do.

Comment: it gives me this error: `Cannot find module '/Users/dheeraj/Project/reactWeb/webpack-dev-server'`

Comment: Drop the `./` from the path.

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal have you installed webpack-dev-server and webpack globally? i tried it and it worked fine when both installed globally.

Comment: modified my answer, this works for me add this to package.json

Comment: @AJS yes I have already installed it globally and tried your new edit also have scripts on my package.json, check it out I have added package.json in my question

Comment: what happens when you just run **webpack-dev-server** in command-line?

Comment: It gives this ```chunk    {0} index.js (main) 919 kB [rendered]
    [0] multi main 40 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3333 3.97 kB {0} [built]```
and whole list of js files & at last `webpack: bundle is now VALID.`

Comment: that means it is working, and it should work with npm with **package.json** changes as well. not sure whats wrong here, should be something silly.

Answer (score 4):

You can run any one of the below mentioned commands to start the node server for your reactJs application:

```
 npm run-script start
 npm run start
 npm start
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Trying URL: http://localhost:3333

Try URl: http://127.0.0.1:3333

And, if http://127.0.0.1:3333 works fine. 
Then for a permanent fix try adding an entry to **/etc/hosts** file as if it doesn't exist or commented

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering as this happened to me with a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04 where `localhost` did not exist in my hosts file and had to be added.

You can check if this is your issue by navigating the browser to [127.0.0.1:3333](http://127.0.0.1:3333) instead.
If it is available you need to add the following line to your `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a global version of webpack and then run script again.

```
    use: https://127.0.01:3333
```

If this is still not working then change port or stop services running on this port