# How to fix npm start errors on my nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

After the npm install, I tried npm start for my project. But it shows an error. How can we fix this error?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn8nh.png)

Comment: This is already discussed over here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478608/npm-start-not-starting-local-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in the wrong directory.

```
cd 02-exrpess-tutorial
npm install (in case you're missing any dependencies)
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

first go the correct file directory.
usually cd "app-name"
(It display this after you create a new app).

Answer (score 0):

There's no `package.json` at the directory where you are trying to run the command. Likely you want to run `npm start` in one of the subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

you're in the wrong file directory ;